# eclipse starts 'Building workspace' in endless loop

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to debug which process triggered a 'Building workspace' in Eclipse?

I have a Java project with some BIRT reports. While this project is open Eclipse restarts 'Building workspace' in an infinite loop.
I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 with BIRT 2.6.1

Comment: Can you try to use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out which operation in the workspace triggers the build? As a filter, limit it to files in the workspace and only write operations. The files touched before a lot of `*.class` files are written is probably interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably related to Win7. I added my workspace repository to the Windows Explorer Favorites or Windows Explorer Libraries. This seems to write some data and trigger eclipse to rebuild.

Comment: Eclipse [Bug 342931](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342931) - Windows 7 Libraries trigger rebuilds

Comment: This behavior is found on both Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: @Old McStopher my issue was specifically related to Eclipse [Bug 342931](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342931). sure there are other issues/scenarios resulting in a similar effect.

Comment: This happens to me on Ubuntu linux as well. Probably this answer is wrong

Comment: Getting this also on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Well, after I removed my workspace form the Windows 7 Favourites thing, the infinite loop building stopped. HOWEVER, when I manually triggers a "Maven Project Update" (right click->Maven->Update Project...) it started up again. So basically it seems the answer is not WRONG, just incomplete.

Comment: Just FYI - this started happening after I added a bunch of WSDL references via the CXF maven plugin. Not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: @demaniak I am also facing same issue, I added maven-jaxb2-plugin /WSDL  and looping of build happens. So I set forceRegenerate as false and seem to stop the loop. but I am not sure how to have it set to true and avoid looping of build

Comment: It shows also on Windows 10. I was able to solve it by unpinning my workspace from the Quick Access

Answer (score 7):

Having something open in another editor in the target directory of the project in which the problem is occurring can also cause an infinite "Build Workspace" loop.

Answer (score 2):

Click Project tab on top of eclipse > uncheck "Build Automatically".
This resolved the issue for me.